# Swipe gesture to hide keyboard inside UITextView

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to hide keyboard when swpie gesture was performed inside `UITextView`. Something like in Messages application. But all I have for now is getting this work while keyboard is hidden. When it shows up the `UISwpieGestureRecognizer` fails...

[image]

Comment: I would try adding a transparent `UIView` on top of the `UITextView`, and adding your gesture recognizer to that view.

Comment: @BlackRider That would prevent any interaction with the text view.

Comment: @rmaddy true, but he the OP could selectively ignore touches on that view, and only handle swipes… Disclaimer: I haven't tried that myself :)

Comment: @BlackRider I can't do this that way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okey, guys... It's embarrassing but to solve this problem all you need to do is to select one option form the drop menu in Attributes Inspectore and everything works like a charm!

Here it is:
[image]

Comment: @motionpotion if I remember you also need to init `UISwpieGestureRecognizer `

Comment: WOW! I didn't even notice this option in IB. Works for me.But in my case, i want a textview to enter message right above the keyboard just like FB messenger style or Vine app comment style. Not sure how to do this?

Comment: Any way to do this if you have to create the `UITextView` in code?

Comment: With code `textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive`, only effective when entering scroll mode, means you have multilines input.